# multi_line does not work with label_parsed?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, facet-wrap

I'm trying to make a graph with facet labels containing an expression and a regular value. But I can't make label_parsed to work with 'multi_line = FALSE'. Is there another way to make it in 1 line? (I mean besides combining the two factors in 1)

example:

```
df<-data.frame(x=1:3,y=1:3,f1=rep("TCRb",3),f2=1:3)
#make label to be parsed
df$f1.<-df$f1
levels(df$f1.)<-"paste('TCR',beta)^'-/-'"
#plot with two factor labels in 1 line
ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~f1+f2,labeller=labeller(.multi_line=F))
```

[image]

```
#now with two lines and the parsed label
ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~f1.+f2,labeller=labeller(f1.=label_parsed,.multi_line=T))
```

[image]

```
#it doesn't work with 1 line
ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~f1.+f2,labeller=labeller(f1.=label_parsed,.multi_line=F))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `label_parsed` for the label for the whole margin (`.cols` in your example) you can parse and keep everything on the same line at the same time.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~f1. + f2, labeller = labeller(.cols = label_parsed, .multi_line = FALSE))
```

[image]

I don't see how to pass an argument directly to a labeller function like `label_parsed`, but another option is to make a new parsing function with `multi_line` set to `FALSE`.

```
label_parsed2 = function(labels) {
    label_parsed(labels = labels, multi_line = FALSE)
}

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~f1. + f2, labeller = label_parsed2)
```